# URI to page or section of pdf

Tags: pdf, url

I am attempting to write a Markdown file for a project that references relevant sections of a large PDF. I can use URIs to link to files, such as the entire PDF, using `file://<pathtofile>`

Can I use an URI to access a pdf on a certain page or section?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125632/is-it-possible-to-link-to-a-bookmark-within-a-pdf-using-url-parameters and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446614/how-can-i-programmatically-open-a-pdf-at-a-certain-point